# how to trigger ok code on press of enter of jQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery

on jQuery dialog box there is OK adn calncel button. while dialog open, on press of Enter it should call the caode written in OK button event.

Comment: Bad practice as the user should be able to navigate to the Cancel button using the `TAB` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was I have written form on dialog. due to that it was sumbmiting form on enter.
But i write onSumbit="return flase;" on form. so it will now only submit from ok button

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#dialog').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        $('#dialog').close();
   }
});
```

Comment: Issue is $('#dialog').keypress() event is not triggered

Answer (score 1):

Define a `function` which will serve both and then use it

```
function onOk(){
 $('#dialog').dialog('close');
// other code to be executed on ok click
}
```

Now attach this to Ok click of dialog

```
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: onOk;
                }
            });
```

And on enter keypress call the same function

```
$('#dialog').keypress(function(event) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) {
         onOk();
   }
});
```

Comment: but issue is $('#dialog').keypress( event is not trigered